# How to receive email, first name, last name and mobile from facebook after login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, omniauth-facebook

```
Devise.rb


  require "omniauth-facebook"

  #  CREDENTIALS_CONFIG = YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root}/config/omniauth.yml")[Rails.env].symbolize_keys
      # config.omniauth :facebook, ENV['FACEBOOK_KEY'], ENV['FACEBOOK_SECRET'], :strategy_class => OmniAuth::Strategies::Facebook, :image_size => 'large'

 Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  if Rails.env == 'production'
     provider :facebook,  'sample_key',  'sample_key'
  elsif ['staging', 'development'].include? Rails.env
     provider :facebook,  'key_sampl', 'key_sdfjkhd',
           :scope => 'email', :info_fields => 'email'
     end
  end
```

**After Login with facebook receiving this hash:**
    ({ extra"=>{"raw_info"=>{"id"=>"846548425", "name"=>"Rakesh PD"}}, "info"=>{"image"=>"http://graph.facebook.com/846548425430988/picture (2KB)
    ", "name"=>"Rakesh PD"}, "provider"=>"facebook", "uid"=>"846548425"} )

**Not receiving logined users email first name, last name, mobile *but the account contain all the informations (email first name, last name, mobile etc)***

Comment: Facebook users using your facebook app can select what attributes to share with your app... you might want to consider a prompt to the user asking for this information to be allowed. If the user removes the required info, you can prompt the question again.

Comment: @TheFabio Is there any permission can i configure in my facebook app or need to do some thing in the facebook account ?, want to receive the email after login.

Comment: From memory (as I had to face this last year) the easiest way for executing my tests was to go into the user's facebook account and remove the app from it. After that from your rails app you ask for the login again and you can configure the permissions.

Comment: I created the app in developer.facebook.com, where to set the permission ?

Comment: don't delete the app itself... in "https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications" you have the link of the app to the logged on user profile

Comment: Yes, Thank you, I saw the app, But this login is for many customers in this system for completing their profile required email information from after facebook login

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86659/discussion-between-errakesh-and-the-fabio).

Comment: The user’s mobile number is not available via API at all (and AFAIK it never has been.)

Comment: @CBroe Mobile number is not required email is enough.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to create a `html/js` text file for you to understand how [Facebook's javascript API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/examples) works.

It will be quick for you to understand the raw data sent by Facebook after the log-in. In particular the restrictions to the data will be easy to spot.

The response to the omnialth-facebook gem is the same as (or very close to it) the one from the javascript SDK.

So if the `javascript SDK responce` produces the account parameters you need, `omnialth-facebook gem` would be able to retrieve it as well. Mind that if the `vanilla javascript` response does not have all the parameters you need, you will probably have to adjust your facebook app.

After some round of experiments I believe you will be able to adjust your `facebook app` or perform the necessary changes in your `rails app`